# How does an array of numbers and its sorted version strictly equal to each other?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, memory, immutability

Let's say we have an array of numbers in Javascript:

```
const arr = [1,3,2,6,5,3];
```

We sort it using the native sort method:

```
arr.sort(); // OR arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
```

Now how do the unsorted and sorted array equal to one another?

```
console.log(arr === arr.sort()) // logs true
```

I am aware the sort method does not create a new array, so they would both point to the same address on the memory.

However, their element order is different, and since arrays are list-like objects, with enumerable indices, the order of elements do matter unlike objects.

So, if all above is true, how are they strictly equal?

```js
const arr = [1, 3, 2, 6, 5, 3];
arr.sort(); // OR arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
console.log(arr === arr.sort()) // logs true
```

Comment: `arr === arr.sort()` compares the reference of the arrays. `arr.sort` is an in-place sort. It doesn't create a new array. `arr` and `arr.sort()` reference the same object.

Comment: Are you sure `console.log(arr === arr.sort())` is logging `true`? It logs `undefined` for me

Comment: More proof: `const arr = [1,2,3,4];
const saveArr = arr;
arr.length = 0;
console.log(arr,saveArr,arr===saveArr);`

Comment: @Tushar Unlikely. See the snippet I made him

Comment: @Tushar you might be seeing the return value of the `.log()` method - it should show `true` above the `undefined`.

Comment: thanks @NickParsons and  - mplungjan, I have used console.log on console which  just returns .log() value. Stupid of me.

Answer (score 0):

`arr === arr.sort()` compares the reference of the arrays. `arr.sort` is an in-place sort. It doesn't create a new array. `arr` and `arr.sort()` reference the same object.

They are strictly equal because both types (object) are same and both values (references) are same.

The comparison doesn't consider the values of the arrays.

`[1,2,3] === [1,2,3]` returns `false`, because the references are different.